# Amazon S3 свой домен

Tags: amazon-s3

Есть домен https://mysite.com
Необходимо подвязать ведро Amazon s3 к моему домену, вроде сделал все по инструкции, но не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Создал ведро static.mysite.com
Выставил в настройках Static Website Hosting
Загрузил страницы index и error (с public access)
Сделал запись CNAME (через ISP manager)

```
static.mysite.com. CNAME static.mysite.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.
```

В Bucket Policy прописал:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::static.mysite.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Если переходить по ссылке static.mysite.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, все работает. Если переходить по ссылке static.mysite.com - не работает (делал 20 часов назад)

DNS Checker выдает следующее: Local NS list does not match Parent NS list

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. ISP Manager сам добавил
static.mysite.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.**static.mysite.com**

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/234027)

Comment: @Sublihim, вроде это ответ... Хотя можно было бы его написать поподробнее...